# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$collation

Tags: php, solr

While Getting the Did you mean Strings from Solr I am getting the Following Warning. Any way to get out of this?

```
if (is_object($results->spellcheck)){
  $didyoumean = $results->spellcheck->suggestions->collation;
 } 
else{
  $didyoumean=false;
 }
```

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: Try `var_dump($results->spellcheck->suggestions)`.

Comment: You've either instantiated suggestions as a stdClass or PHP has done it for you and you've not given it the property "collation". Most likely I'd say is that $results->spellcheck->suggestions is not being setup as you're intending it to be.

Comment: @Ben Solr comes with Collation property if the Suggestion(Did you mean exists) for the query. its obvious hence $result->spellcheck->suggestions->collation may come with null or any string value. I Understand want the error says.

Comment: @str I tried it. Its prints null if no suggestion comes from solr else its comes with a String type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the Collation is null or its exists with an Real value?

```
if (isset($results->spellcheck->suggestions->collation)){
  $didyoumean = $results->spellcheck->suggestions->collation;
else{
    $didyoumean=false;
 }
```

Hope this helps :)